# Java JPA Inner JOIN with WHERE statement

Tags: java, jpa, join, persistence, inner-join

I want to annotate following structure:

I have this query:

```
SELECT A.*, BES.*, BES_2.*
INNER JOIN BES ON A.a = BES.a AND A.b = BES.b
INNER JOIN BES AS BES_2 ON A.a = BES_2.a AND A.b = BES_2.b
WHERE (BES.c = N'foo') AND (BES_2.c = N'bar')
```

I have the entities Job (representing A) and JobEndPoint (representing BES). The Job object should contain two  JobEndPoint which map like a one-to-one relation. I need two JOIN the table two times checking for the same values only differed by the column "c" which I check in the WHERE statement.

```
@OneToOne
private JobEndPoint from;

@OneToOne
private JobEndPoint to;
```

My problem is now that the database columns and the object fields differ a lot and I don't know how to add the  WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JPA repository, and type a custom `@Query`.

I assume you already linked the `parent` and `JobEndPoint` classes over `a` and `b` fields. (To do that, define a multiple-column id on `JobEndPoint` and specify joinColumns in the parent class.)

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM parent 
        LEFT JOIN u.from bes
        LEFT JOIN u.to bes2
        WHERE bes.c = 'foo' 
        AND bes2.c = 'bar'")
Set<Parent> findMatchingParents()
```